# List of names: how to delete the initials in my value

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to change a list of name (1 million names)

```
firstname = ['Jonh V.','Mark','Steve S.',...]
```

To a list of firstNames:

```
 firstname= ['Jonh','Mark','Steve',...]
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following list comprehension:

```
firstname = [n.split()[0] for n in firstname]
```

Comment: still not working, i get this message: list index out of range

Comment: Some of the names in your list must be empty strings. In that case use `[n and n.split()[0] for n in firstname]`, or if you want to filter out empty strings, use `[n.split()[0] for n in firstname if n]`.